# jquery .ajax call to controller, model is null

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I've spent about 10hrs and read a zillion posts trying to figure this out but have to admit defeat, so hopefully some kind soul will straighten me out.

I am trying to send data to my controller (GET) to return a partial view. The model received by the controller is always null despite the variations I've tried. To keep it really simple I've pared the model down to one element.

What am I missing? (Thanks in advance)

Model:

```
public class TextContentViewModel
{
    public string ContentType {get; set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Preview(TextContentViewModel paneContent)
{
    return PartialView("_Text");
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#previewButton").click(showPreview);

    function showPreview() {
         content = {
            ContentType: $("#ContentTypeID").val(),
        }
                $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Preview")',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(content),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#preview').html(result);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("something went wrong");
                }
            });
         };
```

Comment: Try to remove `contentType` property from ajax request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your incoming and outgoing variables should have the same name.

try changing your js variable name to

```
 paneContent = {
        ContentType: $("#ContentTypeID").val(),
    }
```

Also, don't try to use a `GET` to send complex variables. That will NEVER work. always use a `POST`.

```
            type: 'POST',
```

Comment: I had tried POST, but somehow I missed that the variable name needed to be the same. I just thought the property names needed to be the same. Thanks for the assist, I am very grateful.

Comment: @Joel Not obvious that passing variable names must match. It's because the encoding/decoding of JSon. Welcome to SO. Hope you get a chance to answer questions too!